# class property becomes null after viewModel calls it in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

class MainAcitvity

```
fun roomSetup(){
    setFavouriteDao = FavouriteDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).setFavouriteDao()
    repositoryRoom = LorRepository(setFavouriteDao)
    viewModelRoom = ViewModelProvider(this,LorViewModelFactory(repositoryRoom!!)).get(LorViewModel::class.java)
}
```

```
override fun onMovieClick(position: Int) {
        roomSetup()
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "clicked!"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var setFavourite = SetFavourite(movieResponse!!.docs[position].Id.toString(),movieResponse!!.docs[position].name.toString())
        viewModelRoom.addToFavourites(setFavourite)
    }
```

```
class ViewModel

fun addToFavourites(setFavourite: SetFavourite){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
             lorRepository.addToFavourites(setFavourite)
        }

    }
```

```
class LorRepository( favouriteDao: SetFavouriteDao?) {

    var favouriteDao : SetFavouriteDao
    init {

            this.favouriteDao = favouriteDao!!

    }

    private var lorApi: LORApi.LorCalls? = null
    constructor(lorApi2 : LORApi.LorCalls?, favouriteDao: SetFavouriteDao?) : this(favouriteDao){
        this.lorApi = lorApi2
    }
```

I have 2 constructors
one to initialize room other for initializing retrofit
I am Also doubtful about the constructor in Repository. Thoose are made for 2 different purposes, one for initializing room database and other for repository. but everytime I create one object of room/retrofit the second constructor , when called, fills it with null values

Answer (score 0):

My questions for you are:

Why do you to initialize retrofit and room's dao in a separate constructor?

What is it that you try to achieve?

In your code you only call to initialize dao constructor, therefore `lorApi` is `null`.

For your case you wouldn't want to initialize them separately.

Change your code to this:

```
class LorRepository(private val lorApi : LORApi.LorCalls, private val favouriteDao: SetFavouriteDao)
```